# Вывод данных из бд по id

Tags: python, telegram-bot, sqlite

Есть телеграмм бот для сервисного центра авто, при нажатии на кнопку "вывести клиентов" они выходят все, надо сделать так чтобы после этого я через клавиатуру вбил id и открыл этого пользователя и поменял там статус(в работе, ожидает и т.д) через кнопку

```py
elif message.text == "Ремонт": 
#элементы главного меню
markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard= True) 
item1 = types.KeyboardButton('Ремонт')
item2 = types.KeyboardButton('Ожидание')
markup.add(item1,item2)
script_path = pathlib.Path(sys.argv[0]).parent  # абсолютный путь до каталога, где лежит скрипт
connect = sqlite3.connect(script_path / "data.db")  # формируем абсолютный путь до файла базы
cursor = connect.cursor() 
#вывод из базы данных всех вопрос и ответов
cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM client ")
id = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.execute("SELECT Name FROM client")
Имя = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.execute("SELECT Surname FROM client")
Фамилия = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.execute("SELECT Otchestvo FROM client")
Отчество = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.execute("SELECT Telephone FROM client")
Телефон = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.execute("SELECT Marka FROM client ")
Марка = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.execute("SELECT Model FROM client ")
Модель = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.execute("SELECT Problem FROM client")
Проблема = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.execute("SELECT Probeg FROM client")
Пробег = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.execute("SELECT Status FROM client")
Статус = cursor.fetchall()
connect.close()
```